# noSQL and normalised data

Tags: mongodb, couchdb, nosql

I am thinking about starting my first CouchDB project and coming from an ORM background I am concerned how to create my documents that may be difficult to maintain.

For example, if I have the following model :

A *--->(1)B

which means for every A object there is a B object and there are many instances of A that can share a B object. In this case there are pointers/foreign key in A to B.

I could create a document that contains all the A data and the B data. However, the issue I have is if at a later stage (after 10000s of documents are created), I may need to change some data which means I have to update all my documents.

In an ORM/normalised database world I would simple update B and all my references are now up to database.

How do I handle this in CouchDB or is the NoSQL approach not suited for these types of situations?

JD

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The general answer to this question: There is no general answer to this question.

The point is that in NoSQL, the data structure is not dictated by the data, but rather by the queries the data structure must support. So, rather than using the same pattern for each and every instance of a 1:N or M:N association problem, the NoSQL way is to use different patterns depending on your specific needs. These could be, for instance:

- Write/Read Ratio
- Specific database features that make embedding easier or harder
- The types of queries you need to support
- Performance considerations on how the data can be indexed, sharded, federated or in any other way split or cached

Generally, my feeling is that beginners tend to 'over-embed', but I can speak for MongoDB only. Embedding is a powerful feature, but embedded objects are not 'first-class citizens', so it shouldn't be used as a replacement for every 1:n relation. Only for some :)

Comment: Agree. I think one there are two main indicators:
a) How many times do you change the embedded object
b) Do you need to display the embedded object every time the parent is displayed? And if so, on what device are you doing it (e.g. is a query possible or not).
Because if it only changes once every 100000 document, then it is probably easier to store it embedded and once change it vs querying every time the object gets displayed to the user

Comment: Thanks for the info. The embedded object would only change in exceptional circumstances. SO are you saying that I should have it embedded (i.e. the document contains A and B)? Querying is important as it will be used by every request. Please can you clarify a bit.

Comment: @mneomosyn : when you say over-embed, do you mean using references or the document containing all the data it requires?

Comment: I mean documents that contain other documents. I think @rit pointed out some helpful criteria to determine whether or not to embed a document or use a reference.

Comment: There will be a lot of querying and the embedded data only changes in very exceptional circumstances (i.e. NAS server fails and the embedded data is the IP address of the new NAS server)

Comment: @JD. yes I recommend that you then embedd the document as it looks like it is very small as well (e.g. ip address). if you query it a lot you will be very fast therefor.

Comment: Thanks guys. This is my first attempt with NoSQL so I will try and make sure I think about the points you have raised. In the case I need to change the embedded ip address, would you do it offline or do it via the UI like any request (from the UI it will take a while)?